# Spring dependency injection of generic types usage

Tags: java, spring, oop, dependency-injection, solid-principles

I have a question about SOLID design principles in the context of Spring dependency injection with generic type usage. I have the next generic interface:

```
public interface EmailChecker<T> {
    boolean check(T message);
}
```

Then I have two implementations: one for production and one for the staging environment

```
@Profile("!production")
@Component
public class EmailRequestCheckerStaging implements EmailChecker<EmailRequest> {
    @Override
    public boolean check(EmailRequest message) {
        //TODO: some code here;
        return result;
    }
}

@Profile("production")
@Component
public class EmailRequestCheckerProduction implements EmailChecker<EmailRequest> {
    @Override
    public boolean check(EmailRequest message) {
        //TODO: some code here;
        return result;
    }
}
```

And finally over here is a dependency injection of 'emailChecker' field:

```
@Service
public class Receiver {
  @Autowired
  private EmailChecker<EmailRequest> emailChecker;

  public void receiveMessage(EmailRequest dto) {
        if(emailChecker.check(dto)) {
            //TODO: some logic here
        }
  }

}
```

**Question**: does such dependency injection follows all SOLID principles?
Note: I have multiple implementations of 'EmailChecker' interface with different types (for simplicity I described 'EmailRequest' DTO implementations)

Comment: The retention policy of `@Autowired` is Runtime, when you compile the code all your generics are eroded (type erosion), I feel like there is some flaw in your design. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: Spring has a mechanism to inject parametrized beans.

Answer (score 0):

While opinion based, the injected dependency should be explicit via constructor injection.

```
@Service
public class Receiver {  
  private EmailChecker<EmailRequest> emailChecker;

  @Autowired //could actually be omitted since class has only one constructor
  public Receiver(EmailChecker<EmailRequest> emailChecker) {
    this.emailChecker = emailChecker;
  }

  public void receiveMessage(EmailRequest dto) {
    if(emailChecker.check(dto)) {
        //TODO: some logic here
    }
  }
}
```

So that consumers of the `Receiver` class are aware of what it needs in order for it to function correctly

Classes with explicit dependencies are more honest about what they need.  They state very clearly what they require in order to perform their particular function.

Comment: And how does this correlates to SOLID?